# Powershell update for com plus application

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, com+

I'm using the following but i need to set the pool size, which is on the Pooling & Recycling tab for the com+ app to 1 but can't find the corresponding powershell value before the save

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$apps.Populate()
$app = $apps | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $targetApp}

$app.Value("Identity") = $identity
$app.Value("Password") = $passwordEncrypted
$app.Value("ApplicationDirectory") = $appRootDir
$app.Value("ConcurrentApps") = 1 # set to default
$app.Value("RecycleCallLimit") = 0 # set to default
$app.Value("Activation") = 1 # dedicate local server process

$apps.SaveChanges()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have already set the pool size using `$app.Value("ConcurrentApps") = 1`. Might be you are missing something (for example you are not checking that the your set is successful). Look at this example [Configuring COM+ Application Pooling Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I tested by running the script with that value set to 2 but it didn't change the pool size.  So that doesn't seem to be the right value.

Comment: Never mind you were right.  Sorry about that.  I tried to edit my comment but doesn't after 5mins.  wow